# Java and Javascript Socket Issue

Tags: java, javascript, sockets, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome-extension that should communicate with a Java written process using sockets.
Just for testing I've tried the following code , which I excepted to output the string `Ping`.

Java code is :

```
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER); //PORT NUMBER IS 1025
        serverSocket.setSoTimeout(0); // no timeout
        while(true){
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("PORT CONNECTION PROBLEM");
    }
```

JS code is the following :

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:1025');

connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send('Ping'); // Send the message 'Ping' to the server
};
```

The output is :

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 127.0.0.1:1025
Origin: http://www.reddit.com
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: ocm8QWpqeJ2Lps7QJlsoHw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits, x-webkit-d
eflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36
```

Not only I get all the data above, which I didn't ask for, but I also do not get the message "Ping" that was sent using the socket.
I'd be grateful if anyone could tell me what am I doing wrong and point me to the solution,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not implementing a [WebSocket protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers) server in Java, but a simple telnet-like server.

The browser tries to establish the connection as per protocol, by sending an [HTTP Upgrade request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Client_Handshake_Request) that you are getting, but does not receive an expected response.

As a consequence, your `onopen` event never triggers, as from the browser's perspective it did not establish the connection.

Advice: do not "reinvent the wheel" and use some ready WebSocket library for Java, unless you're doing this to learn.